# Horizontal scrollbar on wide image in MkDocs

Tags: html, css, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I would like to display a wide image full height but with a horizontal scrollbar.

This works in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woutervr/8v25o17u/14/)

But it doens't in MkDocs

HTML

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://mermaid.ink/svg/pako:eNpFkMtuwyAQRX8lmjWNPDxim3W2WXVRqWKDwqS2FIPlgJrU8r-XGqSuDojL0cxd4RocgYavxc6D8d-jIyzgBaJAFqiCU0Fb0BX09XtTWT1YRVhNWFVYXVhlmG3AYKJlsqPLI63GHw4G4kATGdD56Ohm0z0aYOUpPehinx-ji8Nf4GbvDzJ-yxabYnh_-SvouCRikGZnI51Hm_ecQO9JBuTGGJZLaWAvgsFs_WcI_5l8B73CE_Sb5B0_dr1sVCtQCcHgBRpFfzxxyYXgSnWtVLgx-NkN2Gy_M2N0dw" style="width: 1000px;" />
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.image-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
```

#### Actual result

[image]

#### Desired result (mockup)

[image]

It needs to be an SVG because it (can) contain hyperlinks
I know the SVG does not have an 'inherent' height or width, setting a width manually is not ideal (better ideas welcome) but that s not the core issue here

Comment: I think you may set a width: ? px; to your image-container.

Comment: wdym? That would be the width of the browser window -- I would want that people with large screens see a bigger portion of the diagram

Comment: Because if the screen is big enough, then they can’t see the overflow as your actual result